# How can I mount a block device?

Tags: c, mount

I have initramfs with /dev /proc /sys /mnt and init binary.
I mount proc sys then dev fine. To log my message I am logging messages to kmsg. I am using printf here just to signify an output to kmsg.

> init.c

```c
int main(){
    mount("proc", "/proc", "proc", MS_NOSUID | MS_NOEXEC | MS_NODEV, "");
    mount("sysfs", "/sys", "sysfs", MS_NOSUID | MS_NOEXEC | MS_NODEV, "");
    mount("tmpfs", "/dev", "tmpfs", MS_STRICTATIME, "uid=0,gid=0,mode=755");
    mkdir("/dev/block", S_IRWXU | S_IRGRP | S_IXGRP | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH);
    mknod("/dev/block/mmcblk0p32", S_IFBLK | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP, MKDEV(179, 32));
    if(mount("/dev/block/mmcblk0p32", "/mnt", "ext4", MS_STRICTATIME, "rw,allow_root") != 0)
        printf("DEBUG MESSAGE: %s %d %d\n", strerror(errno), getuid(), geteuid());
}
```

I can confirm that the mount of proc sys and dev pass given the following result

```c
if(mount(...) != 0 ) printf("Failed to Mount!\n");
```

The message isn't being printed. Printing `/proc/mounts` outputs the following

```bash
[    1.329289]  (6)[1:init]DEBUG MESSAGE: rootfs / rootfs rw,size=3577628k,nr_inodes=894407
[    1.329348]  (6)[1:init]DEBUG MESSAGE: proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
[    1.329368]  (6)[1:init]DEBUG MESSAGE: sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
[    1.329387]  (6)[1:init]DEBUG MESSAGE: tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,mode=755
```

`mkdir()` is also returning an int of 0.

When mounting the block device I am getting

```bash
[1:init]DEBUG MESSAGE: Permission denied 0 0
```

What is causing the block device from not being mounted?

Comment: Don't use `errno` unless you know the previous function has failed. You don't check the return values of any of those to know if they worked or not.

Comment: Can you show us exactly how you're running the compiled code? You need to be `root` in order to create entries in `/dev` or mount filesystems.

Comment: @larsks its init I am running it as PID 1, hence `getuid(), geteuid());` return 0 and 0.

Comment: @Shawn I am using an if statement to display the error

Comment: @BretJoseph No you're not. There are no `if`s in those 4 lines of code. If your real code has some other structure, that's what you should be showing.

Comment: It is rather strange to mount devices directly to `/mnt`, are you sure you don't want to mount to some subdirectory of `/mnt`? Also if you have a shell, try mounting from a shell command.

Comment: You should be testing the return values of `mkdir()` and `mknod()`, too.  If one of those is failing -- for instance, as a consequence of a devfs filesystem being mounted on `/dev` -- then naturally the attempt to mount the specified device would fail.  And it is conceivable that some quirk causes that to be reported as an `EPERM` instead of an `ENOENT`.

Comment: ok let me make a subdirectory and see what happens. I had problems mounting from shell I could only mount it readonly hence me switching to pure c code.

Comment: @JohnBollinger when i run it via a minimal chroot environment directory and devices are being mounted and populated. In chroot the error will be device busy

Comment: In a chroot, you will have a different `/dev`.  It's not directly comparable.  In any case, the fact remains that when you call a function that can fail, you need to check for and handle failures (unless you don't care about them).  You *do* care about failures in the `mkdir` and `mknod` (and `mount`) calls you present.

Comment: Try to set proper `umask()` before `mkdir()`